# Is a subdomain home page URL with a trailing slash equivalent to without?

Tags: url, subdomain, trailing-slash

For pesky trailing slashes at the end of URLs, `example.com` and `example.com/` are equivalent. What about subdomain homepages such as `support.example.com` and `support.example.com/`? Is it the same rule?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The domain name part is processed seperately the "path" part of the URL.   Subdomains are treated the same way as their parents by the web server (in fact example.com is a subdomain of com).

This is maybe easier to demonstrate in cctlds - example.co.nz  behaves the same way as example.com - even though its a subdomain. ( [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and [www.example.co.nz](http://www.example.co.nz) have the same behaviour as well)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!